# Vim keeps freezing/hanging when scrolling out of bounds

Tags: linux, vim, freeze, scrolling

My Vim keeps flashing and freezing (not sure if right word to use) whenever I scroll out of bounds (go too far on ANYTHING).

Ex: 
If I'm on line 1 and try to move up / on the last line and try to move down (this one ESPECIALLY, I use mouse wheel to scroll often so this gets REALLY annoying very quickly)
If I go into command mode and then try to press tab to use autocomplete on file/commands that don't exist

and so on.

Here is my vimrc.

```
  1 set vb
  2 
  3 " incremental search
  4 set incsearch
  5 set ignorecase
  6 set smartcase
  7 
  8 " syntax highlighting
  9 set bg=dark
 10 syntax on
 11 
 12 filetype plugin on
 13 
 14 " autoindent
 15 set autoindent
 16 set smartindent
 17 
 18 " 4 space tabs
 19 set tabstop=4
 20 set expandtab
 21 set shiftwidth=4
 22 set shiftround
 23 
 24 " show matching brackets
 25 set showmatch
 26 
 27 " show line numbers
 28 set number
 29 
 30 " dont use Q for Ex mode
 31 map Q :q
 32 
 33 " make tab in v mode ident code
 34 vmap <tab> >gv
 35 vmap <s-tab> <gv
 36 
 37 " make tab in normal mode ident code
 38 nmap <tab> I<tab><esc>
 39 nmap <s-tab> ^i<bs><esc>
 40 
 41 " paste mode - this will avoid unexpected effects when you
 42 " cut or copy some text from one window and paste it in Vim.
 43 set pastetoggle=<F11>
 44 
 45 " comment/uncomment blocks of code (in vmode)
 46 vmap _c :s/^/#/gi<Enter>
 47 vmap _C :s/^#//gi<Enter>
 48 
 49 " my perl includes pod
 50 "let perl_include_pod = 1
 51 
 52 " syntax color complex things like @{${"foo"}}
 53 "let perl_extended_vars = 1
 54 colors koehler
 55 set backspace=indent,eol,start
 56 "set textwidth=78
 57 set scrolloff=2
 58 "set title
```

Here is the system vimrc (this is at work so I can't mess around with this)

```
  1 if v:lang =~ "utf8$" || v:lang =~ "UTF-8$"
  2    set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,latin1
  3 endif
  4 
  5 set nocompatible    " Use Vim defaults (much better!)
  6 set bs=indent,eol,start     " allow backspacing over everything in insert mode
  7 "set ai         " always set autoindenting on
  8 "set backup     " keep a backup file
  9 set viminfo='20,\"50    " read/write a .viminfo file, don't store more
 10             " than 50 lines of registers
 11 set history=50      " keep 50 lines of command line history
 12 set ruler       " show the cursor position all the time
 13 
 14 " Only do this part when compiled with support for autocommands
 15 if has("autocmd")
 16   augroup redhat
 17   autocmd!
 18   " In text files, always limit the width of text to 78 characters
 19   autocmd BufRead *.txt set tw=78
 20   " When editing a file, always jump to the last cursor position
 21   autocmd BufReadPost *
 22   \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line ("'\"") <= line("$") |
 23   \   exe "normal! g'\"" |
 24   \ endif
 25   " don't write swapfile on most commonly used directories for NFS mounts or USB sticks
 26   autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPre /media/*,/mnt/* set directory=~/tmp,/var/tmp,/tmp
 27   " start with spec file template
 28   autocmd BufNewFile *.spec 0r /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/template.spec
 29   augroup END
 30 endif
 31 
 32 if has("cscope") && filereadable("/usr/bin/cscope")
 33    set csprg=/usr/bin/cscope
 34    set csto=0
 35    set cst
 36    set nocsverb
 37    " add any database in current directory
 38    if filereadable("cscope.out")
 39       cs add cscope.out
 40    " else add database pointed to by environment
 41    elseif $CSCOPE_DB != ""
 42       cs add $CSCOPE_DB
 43    endif
 44    set csverb
 45 endif
46 
 47 " Switch syntax highlighting on, when the terminal has colors
 48 " Also switch on highlighting the last used search pattern.
 49 if &t_Co > 2 || has("gui_running")
 50   syntax on
 51   set hlsearch
 52 endif
 53 
 54 filetype plugin on
 55 
 56 if &term=="xterm"
 57      set t_Co=8
 58      set t_Sb=^[[4%dm
 59      set t_Sf=^[[3%dm
 60 endif
 61 
 62 " Don't wake up system with blinking cursor:
 63 " http://www.linuxpowertop.org/known.php
 64 let &guicursor = &guicursor . ",a:blinkon0"
```

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about the freezing, but the flashing is caused by the very first line in your `~/.vimrc`, namely `:set vb`, which enables *visual bell*, i.e. flashing instead of beeping.

Comment: This fixed freezing issue for me `set noeb vb t_vb=`

Answer (score 0):

I have to echo here the comment by [iefserge](https://superuser.com/users/420840/iefserge). The only thing that worked for me was [disabling both beeping and flashing](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Disable_beeping) by adding the following to my `.vimrc`:

```
set noeb vb t_vb=
```